# How to obtain optically pure mixture from racemic mixture

Tags: stereochemistry, extraction

I recently studied stereo chemistry in school.All i know is that compound are optically active if they have no plane of symmetry and about the nomenclature we follow nomenclature.......

### My questions

> What is the general principle behind obtaining a optically pure mixture?

Comment: Theoretically, Sn1 reaction gives raecmic mixture, more invertion occurs depending upon the time when the carbocation is attacked by the strong base. So refluxing and HEATING a tert butyl alcohol with HI (to avoid elimination) may induce partial raecmization by Sn1. See A guidebook of Organic Mechanism by Peter Sykes. Nucleophilic Substitution reaction.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry SE! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the general principle behind obtaining a optically pure mixture? (correct it as optically pure compound)

You have too many separate questions. In short, organic chemists would tell you that there is full fledged branch of synthetic chemistry in which only one enantiomer is produced rather than a racemate. Read more about enantioselective synthesis, also called asymmetric synthesis on Wikipedia.

Sometimes, it is not possible to produce a pure enantiomer in a reaction. Then *chiral* chromatography comes to rescue. You can separate enantiomers using a special type chromatography called chiral chromatography. Pharmaceutical companies routinely use this approach and more commonly, chiral supercritical fluid chromatography.

Comment: Don't discount selective crystallisation

Comment: Right, but in pharma research, prep chiral SFC/HPLC is heavily used-almost exclusively for obtaining single enantiomer.

Comment: yes, but in scale-up and production crystallisation is still very important

Comment: Thanks, scaling aspect is very important.